# Regex match failing for <change://51736404>

Tags: python, regex

I am trying a regex which matches both `line1` and `line2` below,currently it onlymatches line1 ,how do I make the `problem/`optional so that the regex also matches line2?

```
import re
line1 = '<change://problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms'

line2 = '<change://51736404> [KIC] Not seeing NACK events from tech when packet ex'
match = re.findall("[\S]*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", line1)
print match
match = re.findall("[\S]*(?:change:\/\/problem\/)(\d{8,8})", line2)
print match
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a quantifier `?`, which matches `problem/` between 0 and 1 times:

`[\S]*change:\/\/(?:problem\/)?\d{8}`

Note that you're matching any non-space values greedily beforehand. If your line always starts with this pattern in brackets as such, maybe try this:

`^<change:\/\/(?:problem\/)?\d{8}>`

Comment: output should be `52547719` in both cases,I tried `match = re.findall("[\S]*change:\/\/(?:problem\/)(\d{8})",line2)` ,it doesn't print `52547719` for line2

Comment: So wrap the `\d{8}` in parens like you're doing now, then use `.groups(1)` to extract it from your match object.

Comment: that throws error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the syntax for extracting the group from one match, not from the list findall gives you. Iterate through the list and call this on each match. Also, if you're using findall because you want to match multiple times per string, make the `[\S]*` non greedy (`[\S]*?`) for better performance. Should do that anyway if it will be close to the start of the line

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this expression might likely match our desired strings:

```
<change:\/\/.*?(\d{8})\s*>
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"<change:\/\/.*?(\d{8})\s*>"

test_str = ("<change://problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms\n"
    "<change://51736404> [KIC] Not seeing NACK events from tech when packet ex\n"
    "<change://problem/problem/problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"<change:\/\/.*?(\d{8})\s*>"

test_str = ("<change://problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms\n"
    "<change://51736404> [KIC] Not seeing NACK events from tech when packet ex\n"
    "<change://problem/problem/problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NnKDFR/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/NnKDFR/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: output should be `52547719` in both cases,I tried `match = re.findall("[\S]*change:\/\/(?:problem\/)(\d{8})",line2)` ,it doesn't print `52547719` for line2

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple pattern to match `<change://`, then an optional part matching any text up to the first `/` and `/` itself, and then capture any 1 or more digits

```
match = re.search(r"<change://(?:[^/]*/)?(\d+)", line)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

**NOTE**: If you have `<change://more/problems/52547719>` like strings you may use a small variation:

```
match = re.search(r"<change://[^>]*?(\d+)>", line)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I3qSlv/2).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YisgPL):

```
import re
lines = ['<change://problem/52547719> DEM: Increase granularity of the lower size bins in the packet burst size histograms',
         '<change://51736404> [KIC] Not seeing NACK events from tech when packet ex']
for line in lines:
    match = re.search(r"<change://(?:[^/]*/)?(\d+)", line)
    if match:                 # Check if matched or exception will be raised
        print(match.group(1)) # .group(1) only prints Group 1 value
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I3qSlv/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%3Cchange%3A%2F%2F(%3F%3A%5B%5E%2F%5D*%2F)%3F(%5Cd%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `<change://` - literal text
- `(?:[^/]*/)?` - an optional sequence:

  - `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
  - `/` - a `/` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits